# How to replace ( and ) brackets with space in string using java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am having below string where I need to replace ( and ) this with space

**Example 1**

```
String str = "Somestring 12with (a lot of braces and commas)";           
System.out.println(str.trim().replaceAll(".*\\(|\\).*", ""));
```

**Expected Output something like below **

```
   "Somestring 12with a lot of braces and commas"
```

**Example 2**

```
String str = "Somestring 12with a lot of braces and commas)";
System.out.println(str.trim().replaceAll(".*\\(|\\).*", ""));
```

**Expected Output**

```
"Somestring 12with a lot of braces and commas"
```

Overall I need to remove the ( and ) from string.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Use: `.replaceAll("[()]", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is replacing everything (`.*`) before `(` or after `)`.
You can use:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("[()]", "");
```

Or :

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\(|\\)", "");
```

I'd use the first approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex `[()]` for example :

```
str.replaceAll("[()]", "")
```

**Input:**

```
Somestring 12with (a lot of braces and commas) 
Somestring 12with a lot of braces and commas)
```

**Output**

```
Somestring 12with a lot of braces and commas
Somestring 12with a lot of braces and commas
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do this `String newStr = str.trim().replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "");`